# Extract response output from one api and needs to be passed in the 2nd

Tags: rest, rest-assured

This is my response:

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2Q0JDLUhTNTEyIiwiYWxnIjoiUlNBMV81In0.ezPR0PlML3xO08dEYnJO2QfW8wLc9Hbju1wSqBGM0MEC_YUmsOzQH9X_KvVAH0si7xUVrH74IcLcOlkqGBB5x1ZWQHzh_Zn3ej1JS_n55iXqK1bcOn2dGYjr-yTbIRzxAtUYy8FoV3aEPHwGHh6Ehc3AgOgSSq69ep4CcAUZ38Ga65cd-Aei7dfXMMqtYpHksj6K2TJ3EpFPqqZTfwmLnSomQiWNBC5u6Adkjra5zcQWNRsE2ghcaNQGtMURwjZzeNo4wMWewt1K7CobzS9JPNscK_taOIIhV3vljAf_mRkU7imujdXhchErXoTLD6-cq15txh7xJeo9o1cIm2RDLQ.UCfbgjMC5WsOf_kJsPnQOg.tfvajQljduDdtzwaWaKVxEjr4iEUeo72nS-vag6J35UIdUxdqrQYBixeKjw3vidLN7md2qNRR3fuhzejpkV05DXfyU-bDLa17wn42Ad9L5mId9mNrF9E5oVOGfnrNuoACtCgUp7ntJFBrlhzfNBXJa6AcTOrMSIX5pkXuU4ULhjFw92DqPShbUKCFQFl8UHCmU5u6263t5sSeZmwhmU65fwUeFNnbrMMePYKvRhAOEqe88djreX2j4ErAhBaDQNWVmijtqh32LFHvm_WVX8BmfY5T5-0rfMmRqZXNgesDNEdQRp1FqnSKe9rk22j4DM3y3UiXiMdS2U6eEVD_aeeQZUAqTfS7Q-cWJAxxWQLkrqeMrbLPFD6tfvac_4NQ1sgOG-CNaszkR-_0cwV1c9udQ.9FtyIM8BlR7sQXnO2ILV0CVuhiOy7oxZ8Aol2niJae9apU5T6ff5pynLqsmf6zx1fACne9vW7eNhKfup2LZWUg", "loggedInUserName": "usadm002", "loggedIndomain": "gisus"}
```

I need to extract `token` and use in 2nd API

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) Postprocessor for this purpose. Add the JSON extractor element to the request which returns the above-mentioned response. Then configure it as below:

> Name of the created variables: TOKEN (Any name)
>
> JSON Path Expressions: `.token`
>
> Default Values: NOT_FOUND (The Custom value you want to see by default)

[image]

Then you can use the variable in your subsequent requests as `${TOKEN}`